# Problem with gmail mailbox

Tags: gmail, imap, imaplib

Normally, I use imaplib (python lib.) to display mailbox name (example `[Gmail]/Spam` ) But recently I found my friend account has a different prefix (example `[Google]/Spam`).

What's the difference between normal account and my friend's account.:)

Comment: Be more descriptive, i cant understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that in some territories, e.g. UK, the name 'Gmail' was trademarked and so 'Googlemail' was used instead. Perhaps this accounts for the different mailbox names. [Recently this dispute was resolved though](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=159001), and 'Gmail' is available in the UK again.